# How to get dense smoke from alarm system?

Tags: alarm

I'd like to install a smoke machine to try and deter burglars from breaking in to my property however due to the size of it, I'd need two machines which I cannot afford.

So, I thought that I'd try my hand at a home made solution.  I started with a fog machine as these were easy to replicate and look like some of these professional solutions are based on these principles.   They are also quite cheap to buy.

The drawbacks of these are that they are more for effect and not filling a room full of smoke and that they need to be powered for a few minutes before use to heat them up.  Clearly these are not practical for this purpose.

How do the professional smoke machines work?  Some of which are battery powered so presumably these are not the kw hungry beasts that the fog machines are...  They also do not seem to need to ask the burglar to wait outside for a few minutes whilst it warms up!!

The fog machines use glycerin water mix; are the professional smoke machines also using this formula?

Thanks

Comment: There's got to be  better way to deter burglars. Where'd you get this idea from?

Comment: The effectiveness of using smoke and fog to deter burglars aside, fog machines leave a glycerine residue.  Smoke is going to leave some residue too.  This alarm goes off, you have a big mess to clean up.

Comment: Sorry that sounds a little backwards , “smoke” machines or fog machines use ultrasonics to break up the water into a vapor cloud and blow it out. There are other ways like water and dry ice or Co2 fog. Why not get a proper alarm system with a camera that records , I have 4 cameras where people can see them and additional ones that record to a 2tb hard drive if something happens I have video footage in some cases from multiple angles. I can go online and view the 4 publicly placed cameras but I don’t want any hackers to be able to view the others and know where they are so those just record.

Comment: XY question. Have you thought of extremely loud sirens?

Comment: 4 paws tends to be effective... my german shepherd would allow guests to stay in their seat, but would bark if they tried to move :)

Comment: @JACK this idea came from the commercial versions which are used to protect pubs, warehouses, schools etc.  I'm just trying to make a cheaper home made version.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory The property is vacant at the moment and in renovation so any residue isn't a problem.  Unfortunately the property is a drive away and with no one there to deter anyone, we've had a number of break-ins...

Answer (score 2):

### Do you really want to be the cop stuck sharing a smoke cloud with a burglar?

While what you're describing may sound reasonable to some, it's considered a rather gross violation of the *Life Safety Code*, aka the mother of all modern building life-safety Codewriting (it's not called NFPA 101 for nothing).  In particular, 2018 LSC 7.1.10.1 and it's associated Annex A explanatory text read as follows (italics mine):

> **7.1.10.1* Maintenance.** Means of egress shall be continuously maintained free of all obstructions or impediments to full instant use in the
> case of fire or other emergency.

> **A.7.1.10.1** A proper means of egress allows unobstructed travel at all
> times. Any type of barrier including, but not limited to, the accumulations of snow and ice in those climates subject to such accumulations
> is an impediment to free movement in the means of egress. *Another
> example of an obstruction or impediment to full instant use of means
> of egress is any security device or system that emits any medium that
> could obscure a means of egress.* It is, however, recognized that obstructions occur on a short-duration basis. In these instances, awareness
> training should be provided to ensure that blockages are kept to a minimum and procedures are established for the control and monitoring of
> the area affected.

The 2018 *Life Safety Code Handbook* elaborates on this further (italics again mine):

> NFPA staff has received inquiries from authorities having
> jurisdiction looking for requirements they could use in their
> efforts to enforce a ban on the introduction of artificial smoke
> into a building upon activation of an intrusion alarm. The intent
> behind the introduction of the artificial smoke is to disorient
> intruders and make it difficult for them to travel through the
> building. *Emergency responders called to the building are similarly disoriented, making it dangerous to enter the building.*
> Paragraph 7.1.10.1, by requiring that the means of egress be continuously maintained free of all obstructions and impediments
> to full instant use in case of fire or other emergency, provides
> authorities having jurisdiction with a tangible requirement that
> they can enforce to prohibit intrusion alarms from discharging
> smoke to obscure the egress path. Also see 4.6.1.2, which gives
> the AHJ the authority to determine any requirements that are
> essential for the safety of building occupants that are not specifically provided for by the Code.

This prohibition stems from the fact that the cops who are responding to the burglary call *also* have to contend with the smoke cloud your system put in the air, thus disorienting them.  This has several risks, not the least that the burglar might get away while the cops are still fumbling around for them!  Never mind that our poor, smoked cops might get into a "blue on blue" situation (imagine arresting your own partner, thinking they were the burglar, and that's just the tip of the iceberg).  So, I would stick to the loud siren approach; if that's not enough, video cameras are a much more practical option than they used to be.

Comment: Strobes (commonly seen on fire alarms for the benefit of the deaf) can be highly annoying too.

Comment: Not sure the NFPA will be relevant here in the UK but there are equivalents I'm sure.  There must be some legality (regardless of what the regulations are called here) as these are used in huge warehouses as well as small pubs and commercial properties.